# Sync two sets of folders

Tags: windows, git, version-control

I have a desktop which is used as the main work PC and I'm going to be regularly commuting, so I got a laptop for working while away.

The question is how do I sync the two work folders when I leave and when I get back with no data loss.

I've looked at Synctoy and other syncing programs but with bidirectional syncing there is the case where if I edit a document on the main PC before I sync once back, then I would have edited the original version and that would overwrite the one I worked on while away resulting in loss of work.

I was also considering one way syncing with two syncing options but one misclick and that's the data lost.

Therefore I think that version control of some description would be the best, I've used git a little bit before this, but any help would be appreciated.

Some additional info, the computers when at home are connected to the same network and have printer and file sharing set up.

Additional info 2:
This is non-textual info and I think that the optimal solution would be bidirectional syncing (determined by timestamp) with some source control to roll back changes if something went wrong with the syncing.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "documents", if it's a non-textual format pretty much no version control tool will do much more than say "resolve conflict yourself", but then again, at least you'd get a notification of a conflict.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen so it's non-textual documents so if it was time stamp based that would be fine I just would like something to roll back the sync if something went wrong

Comment: I'd ask your IT department before even starting.